# Initialize vector through input string using for loop in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
 let mut input_player = String::new();
    let mut player_name = Vec::new();
    println!("Enter names of the player: ");

    for a in 1..(player_number+1){
        println!("Enter names of the player # {}: ", a);
        io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_player)
        .expect("failed to read from stdin");

        player_name.push(input_player);

    }
```

I am facing problem while initializing **Vector** through **input string** in **for** loop

Comment: what's `player_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 misconceptions that you have here.
First you are trying to read into the string without clearing it first.

Lets say the first name was `Foo` and second was `Bar`.
After the first `read_line`, value of `input_player` would be `Foo` indeed. But the second `read_line` will not overwrite, it will append. So now the value will be `FooBar`, which probably is not what you want.

The second and more important is that you gave the string away to the `vec` in the first loop iteration. But you are trying to use it in second iteration. This comes into the domain of ownership, which you can read more about [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html).

What you need is a new string for each iteration of the loop. So define a new `input_player` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks Kushagra is solve it by using clone method and initializing new object of the string on each iteration. 
`let mut input_player = String::new();
    let mut player_name = Vec::new();
    println!("Enter names of the player: ");

    for a in 1..(player_number+1){
        println!("Enter names of the player # {}: ", a);
        io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_player)
        .expect("failed to read from stdin");

        
        player_name.push(input_player.clone());
        input_player = String::new();
    }`